# Getting an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line 32

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout

I'm getting an error on the checkout cart page

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object
>   in template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line 32

When I check the line in question its the following

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('file/file')->getCollection();
```

The whole chunk of code is

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$collection = Mage::getModel('file/file')->getCollection();
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
  $sql = "select * from quote_file where quote_id = '{$cart->getId()}' and item_id = '{$_item->getProduct()->getId()}'";
  $fileData = $readConnection->fetchRow($sql);
?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to a module File, please add config and model file code to the question for your "File" module.

Comment: Which config and model file? i'm sorry I'm not to well versed with modules.

Comment: what is the use of this line `$collection = Mage::getModel('file/file')->getCollection();`? if not required, you can remove it.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you very much!